# Preg_replace to get Image link in Content PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm code my poject in PHP5 and MySql. It's include Title, Content. And in Content, it's include Image link. I want to get image link in Content, so i do it with Preg_replace. But it's not working good, Sometime, Image link include another tag, Preg_replace not working with this Image link.

This is my code

```
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $Content, $image);

$image = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $image );
$image = preg_replace( '/"/', "", $image );
$image = preg_replace( '/height=\d*/', "", $image );
$image = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\d*/', "", $image );
```

I try the best to cut tag in image link. But sometime, Content i'm copy from another website inlucde Image link as:

```
<img alt="" height="20" src="http://anotherWebsite.com/images/2014/share-gg.gif" style="border: 0px; max-width: 400px;" width="67" />
```

And it not Fixed Image link.

So, please help me use Preg_replace that working good with all image link. Thank you!

P/s: Content create by CkEditor

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use DomDocument or SimpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

Do you seek something like that?

```
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $Content, $image);

preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/',$image[0],$image);
$image = (isset($image[1]))?$image[1]:'';
```

It searches for the img tag with src, then searches inside the found tag for the src's inner content